# curly bracket issue when inserting scrapy crawler results to postgresql

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

when using the scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell “http://blogs.reuters.com/us/“
```

and trying to extract the title of the url:

```
response.xpath('(//title/text())').extract()
```

i get:

```
[u’Analysis & Opinion | Reuters']
```

and when i run my crawler i get the following in my postgresql database:

```
{“Analysis & Opinion | Reuters”}
```

what I want is:

```
Analysis & Opinion | Reuters
```

How can I make that happen? Also, here’s the pipeline i’m using if that helps:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from targets.items import TargetsItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'reuters'
    allowed_domains = ['blogs.reuters.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://blogs.reuters.com/us/'
    ]

    rules = (
       Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=('blogs.reuters.com', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = TargetsItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('(//title/text())').extract()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

Comment: @bruno,  i like ur answer for the quick and dirty fix that i needed. but once i worked through (conceptually) the item loaders documentation, i went with alecxe because it seems cleaner in the long run. thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use [item loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and [input and output processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors):

> Item Loaders provide a convenient mechanism for populating scraped
>   Items. Even though Items can be populated using their own
>   dictionary-like API, the Item Loaders provide a much more convenient
>   API for populating them from a scraping process, by automating some
>   common tasks like parsing the raw extracted data before assigning it.

In particular, [`TakeFirst()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.TakeFirst) processor. Define your loader:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose

class TargetLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

And load items using the loader:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    l = TargetLoader(TargetsItem(), response)

    l.add_xpath('title', '//title/text()')
    l.add_value('link', response.url)

    return l.load_item()
```

---

Demo:

```
$ scrapy shell http://blogs.reuters.com
>>> import scrapy
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
>>> from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose
>>> class TargetItem(scrapy.Item):
...     title = scrapy.Field()
...     link = scrapy.Field()
... 
>>> class TargetLoader(ItemLoader):
...     default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
... 
>>> l = TargetLoader(TargetItem(), response)
>>> l.add_xpath('title', '//title/text()')
>>> l.add_value('link', response.url)
>>> l.load_item()
{'link': 'http://blogs.reuters.com/us/',
 'title': u'Analysis & Opinion | Reuters'}
```

Comment: @Silas you can put the loader definition where you find comfortable to keep it in. I usually create `loaders.py` file since they tend to grow.

Answer (score 1):

`[u’Analysis & Opinion | Reuters']` is the textual representation of a Python list containing the unicode string `'Analysis & Opinion | Reuters'`. Replace

```
item['title'] = response.xpath('(//title/text())').extract()
```

with

```
item['title'] = response.xpath('(//title/text())').extract()[0]
```

and you should be fine (as long as `response.xpath('(//title/text())').extract()` returns a list of length >= 1, of course).